# Syntax checker for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax, static-analysis, linter

We're looking for a syntax checker for C#, something like Checkstyle for Java.  Does anyone have any recommendations for any tools that we can use?  Ideally it would have a plugin to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, something like StyleCop? There is a plugin for ReSharper as far as I know. You can find it at [StyleCopForResharper](http://StyleCopForReSharper.CodePlex.com). Works like a champ btw.

Answer (score 4):

[FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) or [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis).

Answer (score 0):

The main option for .Net is [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis). It can be used from within Visual Studio.  See also the [StyleCop Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/).